# PHP DOMDocument output HTML page code

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument

I've made a web application in which the user inputs data and then an xml is generated with values from an ms sql server database, since users are going to be using this locally being hosted on a server, I need to trigger downloads instead of saving to a location, and while it does that, the output also includes the HTML in the page, this is the code

```
if(isset($_POST['Enviar']))
{
    $dia = $_POST['dia'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $anio = $_POST['anio'];
    $fechao = $dia.'/'.$mes.'/'.$anio;
    $rifr = 'J'.$_POST['rifr'];
    $cod = $_POST['cod'];
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
    $sql = "SELECT        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.SAPROV.ID3, '-', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '') AS RIF, RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SAACXP_1.NumeroD, '-', ''), 'a', ''), ' ', ''), 8) 
                             AS N_FACTURA, RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(SAACXP_1.NroCtrol, '-', ''), ' ', ''), 8) AS NroCtrol, '0' + dbo.SAPAGCXP.CodRete AS CodOper, 
                             dbo.SAPAGCXP.BaseReten AS Monto, ISNULL(dbo.SAOPER.Clase, '2') AS Porcentaje, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, dbo.SAACXP.FechaE, 112), 1, 6) AS Mes
    FROM            dbo.SAOPER RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.SAACXP AS SAACXP_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.SAPAGCXP RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.SAPROV INNER JOIN
                             dbo.SAACXP ON dbo.SAPROV.CodProv = dbo.SAACXP.CodProv ON dbo.SAPAGCXP.NumeroD = dbo.SAACXP.NumeroD ON 
                             SAACXP_1.NroUnico = dbo.SAACXP.NroRegi ON dbo.SAOPER.CodOper = dbo.SAACXP.CodOper
    WHERE        (dbo.SAACXP.TipoCxP = '21')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conex, $sql) or die('Query failed!');
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $root = $xml->createElement("RelacionRetencionesISLR");
        $xml->appendChild($root);
        $root->setAttribute("RifAgente", $row['RIF']);
        $root->appendChild($xml->createAttribute('Periodo'))->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($row['Mes'])); 
        //
        $a1 = $xml->createElement("RifRetenido");
        $rif = $xml->createTextNode($rifr);
        $a1->appendChild($rif);
        //
        $a2 = $xml->createElement("NumeroFactura");
        $nfactura = $xml->createTextNode($row['N_FACTURA']);
        $a2->appendChild($nfactura);
        //
        $a3 = $xml->createElement("NumeroControl");
        $ncontrol = $xml->createTextNode($row['NroCtrol']);
        $a3->appendChild($ncontrol);
        //
        $a4 = $xml->createElement("FechaOperacion");
        $fecha = $xml->createTextNode($fechao);
        $a4->appendChild($fecha);
        //
        $a5 = $xml->createElement("CodigoConcepto");
        $concepto = $xml->createTextNode($cod);
        $a5->appendChild($concepto);
        //
        $a6 = $xml->createElement("MontoOperacion");
        $monto = $xml->createTextNode($row['Monto']);
        $a6->appendChild($monto);
        //
        $a7 = $xml->createElement("PorcentajeRetencion");
        $porcentaje = $xml->createTextNode($row['Porcentaje']);
        $a7->appendChild($porcentaje);
        //
        $book = $xml->createElement("DetalleRetencion");
        $book->appendChild($a1);
        $book->appendChild($a2);
        $book->appendChild($a3);
        $book->appendChild($a4);
        $book->appendChild($a5);
        $book->appendChild($a6);
        $book->appendChild($a7);
        $root->appendChild($book);
    }
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $name = strftime('backup_%m_%d_%Y.xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $name);
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $xml->save('php://output');
//  echo $xml->saveXML();
//  $xml->save("mybooks.xml") or die("Error");
}
```

I've searched all over Google but I can only find people who actually WANT to output HTML code into an xml

Answer (score 0):

You can not output two responses to a single http request.

Much like an image or download you need a separate request that outputs only the XML and provide the user with a way to call it (Link, Form, Redirect, Javascript).

Comment: I don't see how this relates to anything I'm doing or want, yo see, after the click of a button, an XML is generated then prompted to be downloaded, when you open the xml file you are only suppossed to see the xml data generated, but the xml ALSO includes the HTML of my page (<head> ... etc...), this code is included in my .php file on the page.

Comment: And this are two responses, the XML and the HTML. `$xml->save('php://output');` is the same as an `echo` and `header()` changes the headers for the one single response. The click on the button has to call a PHP Script that outputs only the XML and nothing else.